# How can I get iTerm 2 to copy only what I select?

Tags: macos, terminal, copy-paste, iterm

iTerm2 has a very nasty habit of making an assumption of what I want to copy and paste from the terminal. Instead of just allowing me to copy exactly what I highlight, it will expand to what it considers more useful.

As an example maybe I have the following command

```
rsync <file> server.example.com:/home/user/<file>
```

If I was to select via cursor and highlight `server.example.com`, it will instead re-highlight the entire command and copy that.  It is so annoying because I copy stuff all day long.

I copy by either pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or right clicking to get the dialog menu and selecting copy which is the same as doing “Edit” → “Copy”, on the toolbar.

I have disabled the automatic select text and copy function. That is something I do not want enabled.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: What version of iTerm2 are you using, and what version of OSX? This works fine for me.

Comment: Hi @JoeCasadonte I am using the most up to date versions.  So for iterm it's 2.1.4 and for OSX it's 10.11

Answer (score 6):

It is an option under Preferences>General>Selection. 
I am using iTerm Build 3.1.6.

[image]

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for.

Comment: @Biff See “Characters considered part of word for selection”.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a double-click to select it go into "all-word" mode, which automatically grabs each word.

If you just click and drag it'll take whatever your selection is.

Comment: Hi @Alex, well that's the thing that's not how it's working. I will click and drag and then before I go to copy by wither command+c or just right clicking it will select out as if I did the double click mode.

Comment: this is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Preferences ( ⌘ + , )

Under the Appearance Tab, there is an option "Show tabs in fullscreen by holding ⌘ for:" and there is a slider from 0 - 10 sec.

I had the option set at 0 sec and was getting the issue described here.
When I set the slider to 10 sec, this was not an issue.

I like being able to see the tabs, but do not like it messing with my copy selection, so I went with 1 second, enough time for me to copy the text without it fudging with my selection and showing the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Smart Selection : press 'Edit' then remove all the rules.

From the [documentation](https://iterm2.com/documentation-smart-selection.html) :

> When you right click in a terminal, smart selection is performed at the cursor's location.